# ArrayList Length gets 0 in Singleton

Tags: android, memory-management, singleton

I am using a singleton for fetching data from a web service and storing the resulting data object in an ArrayList. It looks like this:

```
public class DataHelper {

private static DataHelper instance = null;

private List<CustomClass> data = null;

protected DataHelper() {
    data = new ArrayList<>();
}

public synchronized static DataHelper getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new DataHelper();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void fetchData(){

    BackendlessDataQuery query = new BackendlessDataQuery();
    QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();
    options.setSortBy(Arrays.asList("street"));
    query.setQueryOptions(options);

    CustomClass.findAsync(query, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<CustomClass>>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<CustomClass> response) {

            int size = response.getCurrentPage().size();

            if (size > 0) {
                addData(response.getData());
                response.nextPage(this);
            } else {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new FetchedDataEvent(data));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new BackendlessFaultEvent(fault));
        }
    });

}

public List<CustomClass> getData(){
    return this.data;
}

public void setData(List<CustomClass> data){
    this.data = data;
}

public void addData(List<Poster> data){
    this.data.addAll(data);
}

public List<CustomClass> getData(FilterEnum filter){

    if(filter == FilterEnum.NOFILTER){
        return getData();
    }else{
        // Filtering and returning filtered data
    }

    return getData();
}
}
```

The data is fetched correctly and the list actually contains data after it. Also, only one instance is created, as intended. However, whenever I call getData later, the length of this.data is 0. Because of this I also tried it with a subclass of Application holding the DataHelper object, resulting in the same problem.

1. Is there a good way of debugging this? Is there something like global watches in Android Studio?
2. Is there something wrong with my approach? Is there a better approach? I am mainly an iOS developer, so Android is pretty new to me. I am showing the data from the ArrayList in different views, thus I want to have it present in an the ArrayList as long as the application runs.

Thanks!

EDIT: Example use in a list view fragment (only relevant parts):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    filter = FilterEnum.NOFILTER;
    data = DataHelper.getInstance().getData(filter);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
customClassListAdapter = new customClassListAdapter(getActivity(), data);}
```

EDIT2: Added code where I fetch the data from Backendless, changed reference of DataHelper to reference of data in first EDIT

EDIT3: I usa a local EventBus for notifying the list view about the new data. This looks like this and works (initially the data gets populated, but after e.g. applying a filter, the ArrayList I get with getData is empty):

```
@Subscribe
public void onMessageEvent(FetchedDataEvent event) {
    customClassListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: You can try adding a breakpoint on the setter to catch it in the action.  Also, you can enter the following into the watch anytime after the singleton has been initialized: `DataHelper.getInstance().getData()`

Comment: How do you use the class? If you call setData more than once it overrides the previously set data. Also it makes the "new ArrayList<>()" part in constructor obsolete. That is not necessarily the cause for the problem, but can be, depending on how you use the class.

Comment: try making the constructor private and check

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: The setter is only called once, as it should be. I will try the tip with the watch, thanks! diidu: I will edit the question to show it. Vishal: I set a breakpoint in the constructor, it is only called once.

Comment: It still does not show how you set the data. Based on the added usage example list length is 0 because you never set any data on the list.

But it is beginning to look like daxgirls proposal below might be an improvement.

Comment: @diidu I added the complete fetchData method.

Comment: I guess the main point is that you must make sure fetchData is called and has _successfully_ called addData before you call getData. You can do this with debugger or android logging (android.util.Log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally found the problem. It was not about the object or memory management at all. Since I give the reference on getData to my ArrayAdapter, whenever I call clear (which I do when changing the filter) on the ArrayAdapter, it empties the reference. I basically had to create a copy of the result for the ArrayAdapter:

```
data = new ArrayList<>(DataHelper.getInstance().getData(filter));
```

I was not aware of the fact that this is a reference at all. So with this the data always stays in the helper entirely. I only did this because this:

```
 customClassListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

does hot help here, it does not call getData with the new filter again.

Thanks everyone for your contributions, you definitely helped me to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of keeping reference to your DataHelper instance, keeping reference to your list of retrieved items. F.e. when you first fetch the list (and it's ok as you say), assign it to a class member. Or itarate through it and create your own array list of objects for future use.

Comment: I added my usage of the class in the question. So you mean instead of having an instance of DataHelper in my Fragment, I should have a reference on the method getData like this: ArrayList<CustomClass> list = DataHelper.getInstance().getData(filter)?

Comment: Yes. And keep reference to that. If that array list actually contains all your data and unless new data is fetched from the internet, this data is stationary, it will always contain your data. Well, by always I mean, until nullified or refetched, of course.

Comment: To clarify, when you first fetch the list from your helper class, assign this to class member. Then store it in your fragment which retains instance on device rotation f.e. and fetch it if savedInstanceState is not null (after configuration change).

Comment: I tried that (see last edit), however it results in the exact same problem. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Well you can't do what you're doing... see... you're calling the new instance in onCreate and then in onCreateView you already want the result. The result would still be null as your helper class is still doing the async fetching.  And list is not ready.

Comment: Implement a callback in your helper class to have send back message when the data is fetched and ready. Only then retrieve list and send it to adapter. Unless you do that, you're retrieving empty list.

Comment: See my last edit. The initial display works, but after that, the list is empty e.g. when I call the getData with a different filter.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that getData does get called before the data is filled.

A simple way to debug this is to add (import [android.util.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)) `Log.i("MyApp.MyClass.MyMethod", "I am here now");` entries to strategic places in fetchData, addData and getData and then, from the logs displayed by adb logcat ensure the data is filled before getData gets called.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think when I call notifyDataSetHasChanged it refetches the data. Since the initial display of the elements works, this should not be the problem. Only when e.g. changing the filter and calling getData with the filter again, the ArrayList is empty.

Comment: And you don't call setData anywhere? Perhaps there is something wrong in the filtering branch of the if statement?

Comment: What does EventBus.getDefault().post(new FetchedDataEvent(data)); do to the data? Could it reset it? setData definitely does, if it gets to be called.